# How could "C-x 4 b "which pop-up-window but display to the right?

Tags: buffers, window-splitting

In `emacs -Q`, I strike `C-x 4 b` which invoke `(switch-to-buffer-other-window)` and display the other window vertically as

[image]

I reference it's source code

```
(defun switch-to-buffer-other-window (buffer-or-name &optional norecord)
  (interactive
   (list (read-buffer-to-switch "Switch to buffer in other window: ")))
  (let ((pop-up-windows t))
    (pop-to-buffer buffer-or-name t norecord)))
```

It apply the procedure of `pop-up-window`.

How could  use "C-x 4 b" pop up the other window which display horizontally instead of vertically?

Comment: The procedure is `pop-to-buffer`. `pop-up-windows` is a variable. Use `C-h f` and `C-h v`.

Comment: I want "C-x 4 b" to display the other window to the right not below. @Drew

Comment: That's the default behaviour here (`emacs -Q`), showing the buffer to the right.

Comment: No, it does not. @Swedgin

Comment: @Swedgin Emacs by default chooses where to place the new buffer based on the frame's dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the value of split-width-threshold as it works for me when I have wide frames: switching to a buffer in another window splits to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>M-x</kbd> <kbd>windmove-display-right</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd>.

In general, other than binding `windmove-display-*` functions, you can evaluate `(windmove-display-default-keybindings '(control meta shift))`, then you can use <kbd>C-M-S-arrow key</kbd> to tell Emacs where to open the next buffer. For instance, <kbd>C-M-S-right</kbd> <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd>. I think `windmove-display-default-keybindings` is available only on Emacs 27 or newer, but AFAIK `windmove-display-*` may be available in older versions.